# How do we fetch shared mailbox list in powershell using service account credentials

Tags: powershell

Following is the script I used to fetch the shared mailbox list by getting adminId and password. But I want to fetch the details using the service account, can anyone help me out

```
$Credentials = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $Credentials -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking

Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails SharedMailbox -ResultSize:Unlimited | ft Name,WindowsEmailAddress
```

Comment: What service account? What's the issue?

Comment: I need to authenticate the admin user using Admin email Id and the Application Id created on azure portal. Instead of using password as credentials